# Chrome adding extension with modified .crx file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, crx

I am trying to add an extension(uBlock) with some modified preferences for a packaged install.  I am able to have chrome call the extension through the external_extensions.json

**Location** (%PROGRAMFILES(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\43.0.2357.132\default_apps\external_extensions.json 
)

with the code

```
"epcnnfbjfcgphgdmggkamkmgojdagdnn" : {
  "external_crx": "extension_0_9_5_0.crx",
  "external_version": "0.9.5.0"
}
```

Chrome loads the extension but from what I can see it is calling it form the web store so the settings are at a default. I believe that it is not calling this file because I have modified the .crx file and I would be getting errors(displayed below) when I do drag and drop extension into chrome://extensions. However I do not get this error if I do not modified the .crx and use it's default settings.

CRX_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILED or CRX_MAGIC_NUMBER_INVALID

I was wondering is there a way to correctly modify .crx file so that Chrome will accept it or is there a better method to install a custom extension?

**Side note**: I have tried the method of adding an extension by Windows Registry but I still have the same problem with it pulling it from a web store but this method will start the extension disabled. I would prefer this method if I can get the extension to start enabled and contain the settings I want.

**Side note 2**: The reason I am doing it this way and not modifying the extension through APPDATA\ is because this is a remote install, so I cannot have chrome run for the first time and create a "profile" inside app data and the extensions won't exist yet.

Comment: I don't think Chrome has allowed you to do this since Chrome 33 for security reasons.

Comment: try changing `chrome://flags/#extension-content-verification` to `Bootstrap (get expected hashes, but do not enforce them)`

Answer (score 1):

you can add json file to `/opt/google/chrome/extensions` and named that json file your extension id like this: `djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg.json`
in json file you nid to add extension crx source & extension version
like this:

```
{
"external_crx": "/path/to_crx/extension_1_1_0_0.crx",
"external_version": "1.1.0"
}
```

when chrome is lunch extension automatically added to chrome